# Missing return statement error in Java

Tags: java, return, palindrome

I am currently writing a palindrome tester in Java for a class I am taking in high school.  I have asked my teacher for assistance and he is also confused as well.  I was hoping the community on stackoverflow could help me out.  Thank you.

```
public class Palindrome
{
    private String sentence;
    public Palindrome(String s)
    {
        sentence = s;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome()
    {
        if(sentence.length() <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(sentence.charAt(0) == sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1))
        {
            sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
            isPalindrome();
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it matter that this is an incredibly inefficient way to check for a palindrome (since every `substring` call creates a new string)? A simple for-loop over the string would be much better.

Answer (score 7):

You need `return isPalindrome();`. Otherwise the method isn't returning anything in that case, and it's declared to return a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if (sentence.charAt(0) == sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1))
{
    sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
    isPalindrome();
}
```

to

```
if (sentence.charAt(0) == sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1))
{
    sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
    return isPalindrome();
}
```

In order to have the method complied, JVM need to make sure the method has a return statement for every possible case (which is something you haven't done).

Answer (score 2):

If your code takes this path there is no return statement. If your teacher is confused, you need a new teacher.

```
if(sentence.charAt(0) == sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1))
{
    sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
    isPalindrome();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your last if clause misses a return, if you really want to return false in the else-clause.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LucasEduardo, why doesn't this provide an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a recursive way to check if the sentence is palindrome. you'd better to return isPalindrome() method inside following snippet

```
if(sentence.charAt(0) == sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1))
        {
            sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
            return isPalindrome();
        }
```

This is my code:

```
public class palindrome
{
    private String sentence;
    public palindrome(String s)
    {
        sentence = s;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome()
    {
        if(sentence.length() <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(sentence.charAt(0) == sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1))
        {
            sentence = sentence.substring(1, sentence.length()-1);
            return isPalindrome();
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        palindrome p=new palindrome("aabbaa");
        if(p.isPalindrome())
            System.out.println("yes");
        else
            System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```