# Can't print out string from another method?

Tags: java, string, class

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to get the first step of the bingo game done, random call, which is a Random letter from B, I, N, G, O. With a random corresponding letter, but it's not working, error:

```
MISSING RETURN STATEMENT.
```

Can someone help me? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Call();
        System.out.println(Call());

    }

    public static String Call() {
        Random call = new Random();
        int numb = call.nextInt(75) + 1;
        if (numb < 16) {
            return "B" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 31 && numb > 15) {
            return "I" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 46 && numb > 30) {
            return "N" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 61 && numb > 45) {
            return "G" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 76 && numb > 60) {
            return "O" + numb;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing return statement error in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788204/missing-return-statement-error-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the () after `Call`, so `System.out.println(Call());`.

Alternately, you might do this:

```
    String theCall = Call();
    System.out.println(theCall);
```

Comment: Thanks!! I changed my code but there is another problem:  missing return statement.

Comment: --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
E:\ComputerScience\Assignments\BingoGUI\random.java:25: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error

Process completed.

Comment: What does call return if none of the `if`s matches? You don't have a general `else` case, or a fall-through `return` after the last test.

Comment: @user3120509 You need one last `return` statement in your `Call()` function. Whenever you have a series of if-else statements that return a value, you need one more else statement at the end. This is to ensure that the function will always exit with a value.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined Call if you need it to be a variable but if you mean printing the output of the function it should be like

```
 System.out.println(Call());
```

Comment: thanks!! but I still get a error says : missing return statements after I changed my code

Comment: @user3120509 you need an else after all those if(s), so that compiler understands if none of those conditions evaluates to true the else block will return something, hope it's not too late I just noticed you made a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.........Its working for me.

import java.util.Random;

public class Bingo{

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String output=Call();
        System.out.println(output);

    }

    public static String Call() {
        String name="";
        Random call = new Random();
        int numb = call.nextInt(75) + 1;
        if (numb < 16) {
            return "B" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 31 && numb > 15) {
            return "I" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 46 && numb > 30) {
            return "N" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 61 && numb > 45) {
            return "G" + numb;
        } else if (numb < 76 && numb > 60) {
            return "O" + numb;
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java you need a failsafe return statement at the end of the code, so if all your else if fail the program can still return.

It's especially important if your using boolean statements that affect your programs, for example:

```
public void Age() {

    int person = 0;

    if(person >= 0 && person =< 1) {
       return true;
    }
    else if (person > 1 && person =< 5) {
       return true;
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it needs a a final return statement if neither of these are true.. lets say I input 6, Java cannot return anything.

So we add another return as a default. either with another else statement or just a straight return like JavaKumar has done.

```
public void Age() {

    int person = 0;

    if(person >= 0 && person =< 1) {
       return true;
    }
    else if (person > 1 && person =< 5) {
       return true;
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps with understanding the concept.